# Hibernate insert SQL statement not working

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to execute hibernate insert sql query

```
String sqlQuery = "insert into examschedule (class_id,examtype_id,subject_id,examdate,start_time,end_time,messagetype_id,createddate) values";
   String sql1 =sql1+ "("+ classes.getId()+","+
                            exType.getId()+","+
                            subjectName.getId()+","+
                            "'"+sqlDate+"'"+","+"'"+startTime+"'"+","+"'"+endTime+"'"+","+msgType.getId()+","+"'"+sqlTimestamp+"'"+");";

 System.out.println(sqlQuery+sql1);
                query = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
                int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

But, i am getting below exception when i am trying executing same query in mysql console there is no grammer mistake its executing perfectly

Why that values parameters is removed once i call createSQLQuery()) on query object.

```
18:20:16,855 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) insert into examschedule (class_id,examtype_id,subject_id,examdate,start_time,end_time,messagetype_id,createddate) values(13,1,5,'2015-09-07','11AM','12PM',2,'2015-09-12 18:20:16.855');
18:20:16,868 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Hibernate: insert into examschedule (class_id,examtype_id,subject_id,examdate,start_time,end_time,messagetype_id,createddate) values

18:20:16,871 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
18:20:16,871 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
18:20:16,876 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
```

Comment: If you are only going to build a query by concatenating strings why bother with hibernate at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some error in your code i am mentioning in comment:

```
String sqlQuery = "insert into examschedule (class_id,examtype_id,subject_id,examdate,start_time,end_time,messagetype_id,createddate) values";
   String sql1 =sql1+ "("+ classes.getId()+","+
               //^^ here you are adding undefined value remove it
                            exType.getId()+","+
                            subjectName.getId()+","+
                            "'"+sqlDate+"'"+","+"'"+startTime+"'"+","+"'"+endTime+"'"+","+msgType.getId()+","+"'"+sqlTimestamp+"'"+");";

 System.out.println(sqlQuery+sql1); //complete query is in sqlQuery+sql1
 query = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery); //here you are passing half query use sqlQuery+sql1
 int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

Consider and try following snippet:

```
String sqlQuery = "insert into examschedule (class_id,examtype_id,subject_id,examdate,start_time,end_time,messagetype_id,createddate) values";
   sqlQuery = sqlQuery + "("+ classes.getId()+","+
                            exType.getId()+","+
                            subjectName.getId()+","+
                            "'"+sqlDate+"'"+","+"'"+startTime+"'"+","+"'"+endTime+"'"+","+msgType.getId()+","+"'"+sqlTimestamp+"'"+");";

 System.out.println(sqlQuery);
 query = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
 int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

> Please don't to `SO` for debuging your snippet. Read [**What types of questions should I avoid asking?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Thanks, it worked but, i didn't understand what exactly the mistake i did

Comment: Your mistake was you are passing `sqlQuery` in query instead of `sqlQuery+sql1`

Answer (score 0):

You can try executing sql statement in database directly. It will give you any error with the query. Issues might be like adding schema name before table name.